# Outlook C# VSTO Add-In events fired too many times

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in

I'm writing an add-in for Outlook 2013. Emails in our company usually ends with number of conversation item like `note.04`. If user has to reply to one of these messages he or she has to manually increment the number. I want to automatize this process.

I'm using 2 events to achieve this: `ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler` and `ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler`. The thing is these events are fired more than once. The first one has fired 3 times on just Outlook startup and the second one has fired 2 times after I clicked "Reply" button. The result is that when message contains `note.04` and I click reply, the number is increasing too many times, e.g. `note.07`.

How can I make sure this events occur only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the objects that raise the events must be kept alive on the global/class level - otherwise Garbage Collector will release them and no events will fire.

Secondly, why does it matter how many times an email is selected? What you care is the reply event. And it will fire only once unless you set up multiple event sinks on the same item.

Keep a list of selected messages (`List<MailItem>`) on the class level, every time selection event fires, clear the list by unhooking the event handler and releasing all objects there using `GC.ReleaseComObject` for each item in the list, the call `List.Clear()`. This way the event won't fire on the items that you removed form the collection (they may still be alive before GC releases them).
Then add the newly selected items to the list and set up the Reply event handler.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot, but I don't understand one thing: if I have to clear List each time the select event is fired, than it means that the list will always contains max 1 element. Can't I just replace this list with single MailItem field?

Comment: Why just one? It will contain Selection.Count items. Which will be 1 in most cases, but may be more depending on how many items the user actually selected.